# Remove enclosing double brackets from CSV when importing to postgres

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a CSV with 3 columns ; text, integer, text. When i import these all the data is enclosed in double brackets. I'm not sure why. Is there away to remove these on import using COPY? Or should i import as text and then remove them using `select replace` ?

Edit; Code for copy

`copy tavle from 'file.csv' with delimiter ',' CSV encoding 'windows-1251'`

Sample of raw csv data;

```
"TY373543","4510069420","A"
"ND4368","4510093370","A"
"TY152401","4510093370","A"
"TY384054","4510069421","A"
```

Comment: can you post a sample of this csv file?

Comment: Also, please share the `COPY` statement.

Comment: @JimJones thank you added

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thank you added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your target table and csv file have the same structure, I fail to see how it is possible. Follow this example:

Considering the following CSV file  ...

```
x, y, z
"TY373543","4510069420","A"
"ND4368","4510093370","A"
"TY152401","4510093370","A"
"TY384054","4510069421","A"
```

and the following table structure ...

```
CREATE TABLE t (a text, b bigint, c text);
```

Just execute this command:

```
COPY t FROM '/tmp/file.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

And here is your data:

```
   SELECT * FROM t;
    a     |     b      | c 
----------+------------+---
 TY373543 | 4510069420 | A
 ND4368   | 4510093370 | A
 TY152401 | 4510093370 | A
 TY384054 | 4510069421 | A
(4 Zeilen)
```

Comment: Thank you, removing the delimiter and optional parameters makes it work. Why is that?

Comment: @mappingdom I tried several different copy commands and none of them reproduced the behavior you mentioned, even with the delimiter option `COPY t FROM '/tmp/file.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;` Really puzzling ...