# pgAdmin4: Importing a CSV

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to import a CSV using pgAdmin4. I created the table using the query,

```
CREATE TABLE i210_2017_02_18
(
  PROBE_ID character varying(255),
  SAMPLE_DATE timestamp without time zone,
  LAT numeric,
  LON numeric,
  HEADING integer,
  SPEED integer,
  PROBE_DATA_PROVIDER character varying(255),
  SYSTEM_DATE timestamp without time zone
)
```

The header and first line of my CSV read is...

```
PROBE_ID,SAMPLE_DATE,LAT,LON,HEADING,SPEED,PROBE_DATA_PROVIDER,SYSTEM_DATE
841625st,2017-02-18 00:58:19,34.11968,-117.80855,91.0,9.0,FLEET53,2017-02-18 00:58:58
```

When I try to use the import dialogue, the process fails with Error Code 1:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "SAMPLE_DATE"
CONTEXT:  COPY i210_2017_02_18, line 1, column sample_date: "SAMPLE_DATE"
```

Nothing seems wrong to me - any ideas?

Comment: First just try a simple "insert into i210_2017_02_18 " and if that fails reduce the columns you are inserting to. Confirm that works before trying to import

Comment: make sure column SAMPLE_DATE has data in uniform format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your table structure, this import will fail in the columns `HEADING` and `SPEED`, since their values have decimals and you declared them as `INTEGER`. Either remove the decimals or change the column type to e.g. `NUMERIC`.

Having said that, just try this from pgAdmin (considering that file and database are in the same server):

```
COPY i210_2017_02_18 FROM '/home/jones/file.csv' CSV HEADER;
```

In case you're dealing with a remote server, try this using [`psql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100347/remove-enclosing-double-brackets-from-csv-when-importing-to-postgres/50100568#50100568) from your console:

```
$ cat file.csv | psql yourdb -c "COPY i210_2017_02_18 FROM STDIN CSV HEADER;"
```

You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50100347/remove-enclosing-double-brackets-from-csv-when-importing-to-postgres/50100568#50100568).

In case you really want to stick to the pgAdmin import tool, which I discourage, just select the `Header` option and the proper `Delimiter`:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you set the Header-Option = TRUE?
[Import settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixItx.png)

that should work.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Create a table.
you can use a query or dashboard to create a table.

Step 2: Create the exact number of columns present in the CSV file.
I would recommend creating columns using the dashboard.

Step 3: Click on your table_name in pgadmin you will see an option for import/export.

Step 4: provide the path of your CSV file, remember to choose delimiter as comma,

Comment: Welcome to SO, it seems like the OP is already doing the steps that you have written here, please elaborate on why the steps are not working in their case