# In pgadmin/postgresql, how to deal with a file importing issue in which the file is not being read and with the following SQL state: 58P01

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am having trouble importing a file. The table (us_counties_2010) has already been created and the file (us_counties_2010) is in the specified directory. According to the book I am reading, the following piece of code should import the file onto the table.

```
copy us_counties_2010
FROM 'C:\Users\julia\Desktop\us_counties_2010'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

I am getting the following error message:

> ```
> ERROR:  could not open file "C:\Users\julia\Desktop\us_counties_2010" for reading: No such file or directory
> HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.<br>
> SQL state: 58P01
> ```

In pgAdmin 4 expanding servers(1) results in "EDB Postgres Advance Server 12" but the book has "PostgreSQL 10."  I am not sure if this is indicative of running it locally or not.

Attempted the built-in import tool in pgadmin, but with no success:

[image]

Server version: 12.1

Comment: Do you have Postgres running locally on your computer? And if you have, does the user account under which the Windows service runs have read access to the specified folder?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pl59ODaP6no. It hadn't been placed for everyone and full control. Still not working. Furthermore, I am using port 5432.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751203/pgadmin4-importing-a-csv/50756503#50756503

Comment: Tried the built-in import tool.

Comment: Under the heading of Question your basic assumptions, is the file name "C:\Users\julia\Desktop\us_counties_2010" or perhaps "C:\Users\julia\Desktop\us_counties_2010.csv"

Comment: The first one, without the csv. Do the column names need to be exactly the same ? The spelling of the column names for the file and the table that was created differ. Wondering if this is another issue