# sql - pgAdmin4 .csv import is failing

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have been trying to import data from a .csv file into a table (first time postgres /pgAdmin user) without success.

So I tried a simpler structure with only two columns as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
  firstName text,
  lastName text,
)
```

And this .csv:

```
firstName,lastName
Thomas,Johnson
```

My import configuration in pgAdmin4:

[image]

And the error I keep getting:

[image]

I tried changing `text` to `varying char` with enough char lenght without success..

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756503/2275388

Comment: Your CREATE TABLE statement will not run.

Comment: I've seen reports like this several times.  It seems to be a bug in pgAdmin4, and only showing up on Macs.  Does the data show up in the database?  If you look in the database server's log file, do you see any errors report there?

Comment: Is .csv file generated by pgAdmin?

Comment: @jjanes you were right, it was a permission issue on Mac, the .csv file needed to be moved to the /tmp folder to be accessible by pgAdmin4

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file has to be like below

```
"firstName", "lastName"
"Thomas", "Johnson"
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a permission issue on Mac.

The `.csv` file needed to be moved to the `\tmp` folder in order to be accessible in pgAdmin4!